# Debugging an edge use case with IPv6 network on IOS for app store submission

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

A app submitted recently to app store failed in review, one problem was an odd bug which I would describe as an edge use case scenario.

The specific bug was described as

"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.3 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network."

The screen shot provided saying they could not find a file called data.js
This file is part of the app and supplied within the IPA. If it was not all other devices would fail testing aswell. Also the app does not make any external api call's at all unless someone is making an IAP.

How can I simulate this environment with xcode, the simulator doesn't give me an option to define network type?

How is the best way to respond to this with apple? Im cautions of just resubmitting the IPA as they say my developer account can be terminated for failure to fix things previously highlighted review.

I feel like this is a very small use case of users, I would prefer just not to support iPad but unfortunately cocoon.io doesn't support setting a device target when building the app.

Comment: They're just describing their test environment when they say they are running on an iPad on an IPv6 network.  They aren't implying that the iPad or the network are causing the issue.

Comment: Any idea why an ipa would be missing files when used on a different device?

Comment: You don't need to worry about re-submitting as they are very unlikely to punish you for it as long as you have tried to fix something. I would try remaining that file to something less generic, or embed the data.js contents in code and eliminate the loading of it entirely.